# Fast way to make vertices darker?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, lighting

To make a lighting system for a voxel game, I need to specify a darkness value per vertex. I'm using `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` and specifying a color per vertex, like this:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glColor3f(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);

glColor3f(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);    
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);

glColor3f(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f);        
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);

glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);

glEnd();
```

This is working, but with many quads it is very slow. I'm using display lists too. Any good ideas in how to make vertices darker?

Comment: lower the colour values? I do not understand what are you trying to do

Comment: I just need a fast way to specify a darkness (color) value per vertex, because what I'm currently doing is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using immediate mode (glBegin, glEnd and everything in between). If performance is what you need, then I recommend you stop doing *that*.

What you're probably after is a generic vertex attribute. And lo and behold: Modern OpenGL actually has exactly this: Generic attributes. They even went so far, doing the right thing and do away with the predefined attributes (position, color, normal, texcoords, etc.) and have only generic attributes in OpenGL-3 core and later.

The functions glVertexAttrib (most of the time a *Uniform* does the job better) and glVertexAttribPointer are your friends. Specify how vertex attributes are processed using an appropriate vertex shader.

Comment: @LuisCruz: They're the icing on the cake. And sort of mandatory (together with VAOs) in later versions of OpenGL. (I must really say, that with the introduction of VAOs a change of the API away from pointers towards offset would have been in order.)